# python - parse text between two strings and write each match to separate files

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to parse block of text between two strings and send each match to separate file.

**For example:**
I want parse each block of text between "start" and "end" strings and send each match into a separate file.


start

2

3

4

end ---> first block of text to name1.txt

dsfsfsd

start

1

2

3

end ----> second block of text to name2.txt

dfdsfsd

sdfsdfsd

sfsdfs

How can I achieve that please? Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

okay I'm a little unsure about what exactly you're wanting but I think this may be close...

You want to take your matches, whatever they are and find out how to write those strings to a unique file...

You are wanting to put some commands in a loop that will repeat until some criteria is met (i.e. there are no more matches):
Maybe this:

```
def matchfound(str1, str2)
    #You would return the text that you want to write to the file so put your matching code here....
    #If there is no match remaining, return False

counter=1
while 1:
    x=matchfound(var1,var2)
    if x:
        f=open('Name'+str(counter)+'.txt', 'w')
        f.write(x)
        f.close()
        counter+=1
    else:
        break
```

If this isn't exactly what you are wanting post a snippit of your code so I could get a better look at what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello,

code:
`inputFile = open("original_file.txt")
outputFile = open("output.txt", "w")
buffer = []
for line in inputFile:
    if line.startswith("START OF THE BLOCK"):
        buffer = ['']
    elif line.startswith("END OF THE BLOCK"):
        outputFile.write("".join(buffer))
        buffer = []
    elif buffer:
        buffer.append(line)
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()`

This finds each block of text between "START OF THE BLOCK" and "END OF THE BLOCK". But this wrote each block of the text to the one file and I want put each founded block of text to the separate file.